# Proving inequality with induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$$ 
0!+1!+...+n! \leq n!\bigg(\dfrac{1}{0!}+\dfrac{1}{1!}+...+\dfrac{1}{n!}\bigg)
$$

How can I prove this inequality for $n\geq 1$? Actually I can see that when you divide both sides with $n!$ lhs is never greater than $2$ and rhs is always greater than or equal to $2$. I mean,
 $P(n) \leq 2 \leq G(n)$. But obviously that wouldn't be a proof. I am too lost in in the inductive step. How can I derive $P(n+1)$ from $P(n)$ to prove this inequality?

What I tried was adding both sides $(n+1)!$ but I couldn't make my way through that. Now I'm multiplying both sides with $(n+1)$. It's going like this

Suppose

$$ 
0!+1!+...+n! \leq n!\bigg(\dfrac{1}{0!}+\dfrac{1}{1!}+...+\dfrac{1}{n!}\bigg)
$$

Multiply with (n+1) to get

$$ 
0!(n+1)+1!(n+1)+...+(n+1)! \leq (n+1)!\bigg(\dfrac{1}{0!}+\dfrac{1}{1!}+...+\dfrac{1}{n!}\bigg)
$$
But this means

$$ 
0!+1!+...+n!+(n+1)! \leq (n+1)!\bigg(\dfrac{1}{0!}+\dfrac{1}{1!}+...+\dfrac{1}{n!}\bigg)
$$

As you can see I got the lhs in the form of P(n+1) but still on my way for the rhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LHS is $\sum_o^nk!$, RHS is $\sum_0^n\frac{n!}{k!}=\sum_0^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.

Note that $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=k!$$n\choose k$$\geq k!$, so the RHS is greater term-by-term.

Hence, it is also greater overall.

Induction proof:

Let $L(n)=0!+1!+...+n!, R(n)=n!(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+...\frac{1}{n!})$.

Then, $L(n+1)=L(n)+(n+1)!$, $R(n+1)=(n+1)R(n)+1$.

Then, $R(n+1)-L(n+1)=R(n)-L(n)+[nR(n)+1-(n+1)!]$

Noting that $R(n)\geq 2(n)!$ for $n\geq1$, then $nR(n)+1-(n+1)!\geq2n(n)!+1-(n+1)!=n!(2n+\frac{1}{n!}-(n+1))=n!(n-(1-\frac{1}{n!}))\geq0$

As such, $R(n)-L(n)$ grows with $n$, and as it's equal to $0$ for $n=0,1$, we see that $R(n)-L(n)\geq0$ for all $n$, whence $R(n)\geq L(n)$ and the inequality is proved.

Comment: simple and plain, upvoted thanks. But I'd like to see how this can be achieved with mathematical induction too. Because you know I've been dealing with this question like 3-4 hours trying to prove it by induction.

Comment: @user2694307 yep, realised i misread first time over - have added an induction proof

Comment: $R(n+1) = (n+1)R(n) + 1$. How would this have $(+...+1/n! + 1/(n+1)!)$ in $R(n+1)$?

Comment: Well, $\frac{R(n+1)}{(n+1)!}=\frac{R(n)}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. Then multiply both sides by $(n+1)!$.